# Save mysql query into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to allow users (In my place of work) to run a query, and if they choose, save it into a database so that they can just run it again later with a single click (Like if they are updating a database). I am having a problem with this, though. Simply running the query isn't an issue, but the query doesn't save correctly. The query is something like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/to/file/file.txt' INTO TABLE table FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I can get it to save into the database correctly if I escape the backslashes when typing out the query, but that causes the query to run incorrectly on submit. I am wondering if there is a way that I can automatically escape backslashes. Or would it just be easier/better to separate the two features? If any more information is needed let me know, and thanks in advance.

Comment: When reading the query back in could you use REPLACE - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace to change \\ to \ ?

Comment: Have you tried using prepared statements? In that case you don't need to escape the data. Anyways, if you want to escape before adding to the database, then just unescape when you retrieve it!

Comment: Have you tried `mysqli_real_escape_sting()` (or similar) or as suggested above use prepared statements to insert the record (thus avoiding the need to escape at all)?

Comment: I have tried `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. I get this as a result:

LOAD DATA INFILE \'path/to/file/file.txt\' INTO TABLE table FIELDS TERMINATED BY \' \' LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\';

It keeps the \n, but still messes up the \t

Comment: Encode the file contents as 'base64' (base64_encode) before storing it? 'base64_decode' when displaying it. Note: 'base64 encoding' is 'database' and 'HTML' 'safe'.

Answer (score 1):

I did some tinkering, and I got it. Here is the solution I came up with:

First, I used `str_replace` on the update.

```
$q = str_replace(array("\t", "\n"),array("\\t","\\n"), $_POST['update']);
```

Then, I prepared it as suggested.

```
if($stmt = $con->prepare("insert into queries (Query_Name, Query, Description) values (?, ?, ?);")){
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $qn, $q, $qd);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Finally, I ran a `mysqli_multi_query` (because sometimes there is more than one query in a submission, which caused it to fail) to run the query(s) the user puts in.

```
$query = mysqli_multi_query($con, $q);
```

Thanks to everyone who offered suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You have to unescape the query before using it.
Create a method dedicated to run queries from the database like "`myClass->unescapeAndExecute($escapedQueryFromDb);"`